# never an element take specific class in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors

I'm writing a jquery code that if clicked on element, this element give a class. Now I want that specific element never take a specific class.

Summary:

```
$('element').*never take a specific class*
```

HTML CODE:

```
<article class="wrapper ui-widget-content">
<div class="ui-widget-header">SSSSSS </div>
<ul id="selectable">
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>HHHH</span> </li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>CCCC</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>JJJJ SCRIPT</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>AAAA</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>XXX</span></li>
    <li class="ui-state-default"><span>MMMMM</span></li>
</ul>
</article>
```

according to jquery code when i'm  clicked to every `<li>`, this has take "ui-selected" class, but Sometimes `<span>` tag also take "ui-selected" class.
i want `<span>` never take this class : "ui-selected"

Comment: So why haven't you shown your jQuery? If we can see it we can correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('li').click(function(){
    if($(this).find('span').hasClass('your_class_here'))
    $(this).find('span').removeClass('your_class_here');
});
```

Check every time when you click on li if your class was added to your span. If yes remove it.

Comment: thanks, but i have a quastion...  why sometimes i have twice click on li to be selected or deselected? when i clicked once possible deselected not woek....

Comment: Post the click function here

Comment: $("#selectable" ).selectable({
            selected: function (event, ui) {$(ui.selected).bind('click',function(){
    if($(ui.selected).hasClass('ui-state-default')){
     $(this).removeClass('ui-srate-default').addClass('ui-srate-active')
     }
    
    
     })
   }